# Why Gutter doesn't show line numbers on TSynEdit?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, syntax-highlighting

We use `TSynEdit` as syntax highlighting editor for Delphi XE2. All works great except one. It doesn't show line numbers on Gutter. What's wrong? How to fix this issue?

Comment: Duplicates are very useful to find an answer by different ways. Why does StackOverflow hate them?

Comment: It doesn't hate duplicate questions. It hates duplicate *answers* because it wastes people's time. Duplicate questions get closed so that they don't accumulate answers that should be at the other copy of the question. Duplicate questions *do* help searches. When people find this question, they'll be directed to the answers at the other question.

Comment: But sometimes people set duplicate link to another question without proper actual solution but with a lot of answers and too much text. Then they close the new question (without 5 votes!). And this is very bad practice.

Comment: So answer the original question instead of the new one. If you don't like how thing are done, take up the issue on the [meta] site. The only way a question can be closed with fewer than five votes is if a moderator closes it; such is the power and privilege of moderators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to set the property:

```
SynEdit.Gutter.ShowLineNumbers := True;
```